# How to set a margin using bootstraps btn-block?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to add a margin to my buttons while using bootstrap's btn-block. Unfortunatelly it does not do what I wanted to, because the button doesn't shrink. The button goes out of it's div.

Under this text you can see what I mean. Both buttons contain bootstraps 'btn-block' element. The button above has a margin.

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;">No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block black-button">Yes</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Does somebody know how I can apply a margin to the button at a way that the button stays in the above div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give padding to your container div. Not to buttons

```
<div style="width:90%; padding:0 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" >No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block black-button">Yes</button>
</div>
```

you can see the example : https://codepen.io/tsdln/pen/OgLYrE

Comment: Great. This is an easy and working trick. The codepen update works, but you made a writing error in the code example above; width should be 100% instead of 90%. Thanks!

Comment: a fast and good solution. although I wouldn't embed styles in the html, this is 2017 after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the button in `div` tags, and put the style in there.

```
<div>
    <div style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block black-button">Yes</button>
</div>
```

That way, the button will only expand to fill you margin'd div, not the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a great framework but they don't and can't have every possible use case covered. I don't know how others do it but I have a separate CSS file I load after the BS theme (I call it overrides.css) and I keep in it things like:

```
.no-margin, .no-margins { margin:0px !important; }
.no-padding, .no-paddings { padding:0px !important; }
@media only screen and (max-width:651px) {
   .mobile-no-margin, .mobile-no-margins { margin:0px !important; }
   .mobile-no-padding, .mobile-no-paddings { padding:0px !important; }
}
```

Then I just apply those classes wherever I need to.

If you are concerned about one extra hit and don't have an asset pipeline you can just put something like this at the end of the bootstrap stylesheet.